# Full text search in Electron BrowserWindow

Tags: node.js, chromium, electron

Does the [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) application framework have built-in text search?

The [quick-start application](https://github.com/atom/electron-quick-start) doesn't provide any apparent search functionality (e.g. using `Ctrl-F` or from the menu options). I would have expected this to be a [BrowserWindow](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md) option (or an option of its [WebContents](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md)), but I don't see anything helpful in the docs.

Comment: The electron browswe window isn't a browser window like you web browser has one! As far as I know the browser window is only used to deliver the gui... And because of that it doesn't have any browser like functions

Comment: @Coretool: I think Electron does more than simply deliver the GUI (e.g. developer tools). That said, you're right that search is not supported: https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/2037

Comment: Ok, thanks for the correction, wasn't 100% sure...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I know this is an old thread, but might still be relevant for people out there.
Had the same problem, and first fixed by using [electron-in-page-search](https://github.com/rhysd/electron-in-page-search), but this component doesn't work properly with Electron 2 or greater.

Then finally found [electron-find](https://github.com/TheoXiong/electron-find) resolved my problem. Using with Electron 4.

You just add the component to your project:

```
npm install electron-find --save
```

Add a global shortcut in your Electron main process to send an event to the renderer in a ctrl+f:

```
globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+F', () => {
    window.webContents.send('on-find');
});
```

And then you can add this to your page (the renderer process)

```
const remote = require('electron').remote;
const FindInPage = require('electron-find').FindInPage;

let findInPage = new FindInPage(remote.getCurrentWebContents());

ipcRenderer.on('on-find', (e, args) => {
  findInPage.openFindWindow()
})
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This no more works for me on electron 8 . We need a new solution or update https://github.com/TheoXiong/electron-find.

Comment: @БогуславПавлишинець from electron 14, the "remote" module is removed and is replaced with "@electron/remote" module, so i create a fork to  use "@electron/remote" to support electron 14 to 21 : https://github.com/iamqiz/electron-find-fork

Answer (score 9):

Try [webContents.findInPage](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#webcontentsfindinpagetext-options) just added in the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the solution Robson Hermes offered. `globalShortcut` is, by definition, global, so the shortcut will be detected even when the app is not focused. This will result in the Ctrl+F shortcut being "stolen" from everywhere else.

I have found no ideal solution (see [this issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1334) on the electron repository), but a hacky one can be achieved by doing what Robson said and adding

```js
win.on('focus', () => {
  globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+F', () => windows.main.send('on-find'))
})
win.on('blur', () => {
  globalShortcut.unregister('CommandOrControl+F')
}
```

Note that as seen [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8491#issuecomment-274790124), this is not ideal and can lead to several issues:

> 1. Other applications can get a lock on the shortcut when you lose focus, i.e. the shortcut will magically stop working when you switch back to the app later.
> 2. Some apps can appear on screen without taking focus (spotlight I believe has this behavior) and during the app's appearance the shortcuts will still be captured by your application.
> 3. There's also gonna be those weird one in a thousand situations where somehow you switch focus and the shortcut is not removed.

Comment: Good point, @Eva. Maybe could replace the `globalShortcut` with a handling of `before-input-event` ?  As per the docs [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-before-input-event), could check what keys were pressed in the event.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using global shortcuts , use Accelerators ( normal Keyboard shortcut )

```
{
label : 'help',  
   click : function(){. 
                electron.shell.openExternal('http://....'). 
           },
   accelerator : 'CmdOrCtrl+ Shift + H'
}
```

The above shown is just an example of How to use accelerator