# How to make page search on electron like in Chrome or VS Code or Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, electron, selection, browser-api

[This is how the search looks like in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0D34.png)

I tried to make something like this but I meet some problems.
I use `Window.getSelection()` to highlight all matches, and separate input to get user query. But it does not highlight all added ranges like Firefox do, and I cannot get focus on input and in the same time highlight found text.

I have problems with focus and highlighting.

[This is what I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koTTI.png)

I know that Chrome and Firefox and VS Code and Atom all have this feature, they have highlighting that belongs to user-selection, and they have highlighting that belongs to search results. They probably have independent Selection objects for search results and for user-selection. Is there any ready API for that or I need to try to implement it myself?

Thank you all)

Comment: There is a ready-to-use package for that, electron-find: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55493950/105224

Comment: That package is out of date. It is tested on electron 4, and It does not work for me on electron 8.

Comment: Hmm, I use it on my electron project and I'm on electron 9.1.1. Just checked, it still works - ah no. Sorry. I copied the sources into my project and patched it.

Comment: I tried it but it do not want to work for me, so I have created my own page_search. You can try it on my app even online -=> https://bolls.life. Just press `ctrl + shift + F` and go on